# How to communicate through server using Tizen TV OS?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

Is it possible to stream content from the server on TV? I'm searching everywhere and not able to find how can we connect to the server through the TV os. What type of app can support this functionality?

One more query is it possible to Turn on the TV device through the server or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily build streaming apps using either HTML5 video element:

- http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/multimedia/media-playback/using-video-elements

or the AVPlay API:

- http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/multimedia/media-playback/using-avplay

Here are a few samples that could help you to get started:

https://github.com/Samsung/TizenTVApps

Answer (score 0):

The general structure of a web app on a TIZEN display:

- A web application consisting of HTML/CSS/JS/etc packed into a .wgt archive via either TIZEN Studio or TIZEN IDE;
- That .wgt file placed somewhere on your server;
- Along with the .wgt file there needs to be a sssp_config.xml, which tells a display attempting to connect to your server what widget to look for;
- TIZEN display must be set to URL launcher as source;
- URL of your server entered into the display as the URL to connect to;

The display will connect using the URL launcher option to the URL you specified in the URL launcher settings on the display. It will then check the sssp_config.xml that is on your server to see what the widget it is supposed to download is called. After that it will download the .wgt file and install the app on the TIZEN system, i.e. on the display.

Your web application can now be started like any web application using the URL launcher of the display. Data can be retrieved from your server by your app running on the display, either with standard calls such as AJAX or by using TIZEN API such as the Download API.